# Javadoc through Ant task with {@inheritDoc} from J2SE classes

Tags: java, ant, javadoc, inheritdoc

I generate documentation for a project using an Ant task. In several places, I wanted to inherit documentation from the standard classes, so I used `{@inheritDoc}` which allowed me to see the Javadoc in Eclipse, but it wouldn't show up in the HTML files. The problem was that I hadn't included the unzipped src.zip (J2SE source) in the sourcepath. Having fixed that, I now get several hundred warnings about the use of Sun proprietary API in files like `lib/jdk-src/java/lang/Class.java`.

Is there any way to suppress these warnings? It's hard to find relevant problems in this mess.

A possible solution I thought of was to run the Javadoc task once without including the J2SE source in the sourcepath, which will reveal any real issues. Then I can run Javadoc a second time with the J2SE source included, discarding the output altogether, which will produce documentation with properly-working `{@inheritDoc}`s. I'm not entirely sure about the best way to accomplish this in Ant, not to mention that running Javadoc twice would be a dirty fix.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the solution you're looking for, but you might try [`-link` *extdocURL*](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#link). That way you'll at least get the ["Overrides"](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#inheritingcomments) or ["Specified by"](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#inheritingcomments) links for overridden or implemented methods, respectively. For developement libraries, the [`-linksource`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#linksource) option is handy, too.